# How to add a number to an existing array in redux react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I want to update Array

initialState

```
const initialState = { name:'a', arrNames:[1,2,3,4]}
```

reducer

```
const userRuducer = createReducer(initialState,(builder)=>{   
    
    builder.addCase('UPDATE_ARRAY',(state,action)=>{
        // how to add ' 12' in the arraay
    })
})
```

component

```
 <Button onClick={() =>dispatch({type:'UPDATE_ARRAY',payload:12}) } variant='contained'>update Array</Button>
```

result:-

```
arrNames:[1,2,3,4, 12]
```

Comment: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createreducer

Answer (score 1):

You are using redux-toolkits so it basically just push the new item to the object:

```
builder.addCase("UPDATE_ARRAY", (state, action) => {
  state.arrNames.push(action.payload)
};
```

Because redux-toolkits already included with [immerjs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers#immutable-updates-with-immer)

Answer (score 0):

```
builder.addCase("UPDATE_ARRAY", (state, action) => {
  return {
    ...state,
    arrNames:[...state.arrNames,action.payload]
  };
})
```

here the state is immutable and conceded as better practice